# did postman change their UI? how do i make requests with it now

Tags: postman

it looks like postman changed their ui and I can no longer send test requests to api endpoints in my collections.  how do i go back to the old UI? this one is garbage.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you've probably entered `Browse` mode. There are two modes in the postman app, `Browse` and `Build`. You can switch modes from a switch located at the bottom right.